# NLog: Unexpected beheavior of IsTraceEnabled

Tags: c#, nlog

I have some doubts on the result of `IsTraceEnabled` (also equivalent functions `IsDebugEnabled`....).

If I call `NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("TEST")` than I get a unexpected response `true`

```xml
<rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="TEST" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" final="true"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile">
      <filters>
        <when condition="equals('${logger}','System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="equals('${logger}','XPO')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
```

---

Anyone have an idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final attribute is applied in combination with the (min)level rule and name(filter).

So in your case:

```xml
 <logger name="TEST" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" final="true"/>
```

If the logger is "TEST" and the minimum level is error, then write to logfile  and mark as final.

As your logevent is written as debug, it's not matching the first rule, but it does match the second.

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile">
   ...
</logger>
```

Comment: If I remove the final attribute I have the same problem

Comment: yes, without the final attribute is, the 2nd rule applies. The filters in the 2nd rule are evaluated when logging (e.g. it could also be "message length < 10", so that rule is is enabled for the logger "TEST"

Comment: Is there any other possiblity to check if a loglevel is enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately only by checking the rules yourself